# how do you build a linear model not knowing the column names in data frame?

Tags: r

I need to build a linear model given a data frame:

```
structure(list(cpu = c(6, 10, 20), Date = c(1425031717000, 1425031957000, 
1425032197000)), .Names = c("cpu", "Date"), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

In this case I know the columns names I can do this:

```
lm(cpu~Date, data=dat)
```

I need to generate columns names dynamically. I need to create a function and need to extract column names from data frame when I am ready to call the lm function. Column names can be anything depending on the data frame.

I tried this;

```
lm(names(dat[1])~names(dat[2]), data=dat)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
In model.response(mf, "numeric") : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help, found by typing `?formula`, says

> There is a formula method for data frames. If there is only one
>   column this forms the RHS with an empty LHS. For more columns, the
>   first column is the LHS of the formula and the remaining columns
>   separated by + form the RHS.

So `formula(dat)` as the first arg to `lm` does it:

```
lm(formula(dat),data=dat)
```

resulting in

```
Call:
lm(formula = formula(dat), data = dat)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         Date  
 -4.156e+07    2.917e-05
```

Comment: @Frand, Thank you Frank this works also. The challenge that I am having is this. I have to build a function and based on the arguments in the function, I have to build the linear model. For example, let's say my x<-c("cpu"), y<-c("Date") in my Date frame. Pred function will call like this: Pred(x,y) that will then needs to be like this: lin<-lm(x~y, data=dat)

Comment: @user1471980 So long as your model is linear, this general approach works. You can rearrange or subset the columns of `dat`:  `lm(formula(dat[c(5,8:12)]),data=dat)` where column 5 is your regressand (RHS variable) and columns 8:12 are your regressors. If you're talking about knowing the columns' names but not their numbers, well, that's a different question. In that case, you should just paste stuff together: `paste(x,paste(y,sep="+"),sep="~")` where x is a name and y can be a vector of names.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not care of having the names of the columns in the resutls you can go with:

```
lm(dat[[1]]~dat[[2]])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lm(as.formula(paste(names(dat)[1],names(dat)[2],sep="~")), data=dat)

Call:
lm(formula = as.formula(paste(names(dat)[1], names(dat)[2], sep = "~")), 
    data = dat)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         Date  
 -4.156e+07    2.917e-05
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use all variables you create , use " ~. " in R. Else you may modify the loop to keep just the fields you need.

```
    Df <- structure(list(cpu ..--your data---)

    ##for loop##

    vars=colnames(Df)[-1]
    for (i in vars) {
    lm.fit <- lm(paste("cpu ~", i), data=Df)
    }

    summary(lm.fit)
```

Comment: I don't think you can write "cpu ~" in the solution, since the question assumes the names are not known. Also, your loop just overwrites `lm.fit` many times. Maybe you meant to store the results from each iteration in a list? Oh, also `lm.fit` is the name of a function already, so you probably don't want to re-use that name.

Comment: thanks! the above code just provides a frame. It can be modified as per need.